# IIS tilde vulnerability

Tags: iis, vulnerability

I have the same problem as mentioned here [Fixing the IIS tilde vulnerability](https://serverfault.com/questions/670658/fixing-the-iis-tilde-vulnerability) and have applied all suggested fixes:

- 8dot3 naming disabled on all drives
- 8dot3 names stripped from c:\inetpub\wwwroot
- fsutil & dir /x scan completed and no 8dot3 names found
- IIS Request filtering deny rule and deny URL in place

I'm still getting a result of vulnerable when using the  [IIS Shortname Scanner PoC](https://soroush.secproject.com/blog/tag/short-name-scanner/) tool with the below result:

IIS Short Name (8.3) Scanner version 2.3.8 (25 February 2016) - scan initiated
 2017/03/06 20:10:05

- Target: https://website.name.com/
- Result: Vulnerable!
- Used HTTP method: DEBUG
- Suffix (magic part): /a.aspx
- Extra information:

  - Number of sent requests: 145

This to me doesn't really help identify where the problem lies and that it's simply still vulnerable. The command I'm using is:

```
java -jar iis_shortname_scanner.jar 2 20 https://website.name.com/
```

I have three app servers sitting behind a load balancer but as long as the servers have been fixed I can't see why this would make a difference....

I thought it better to start a new question as the other thread had been addressed and a successful fix provided but not the case for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix this by adding the [URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to IIS on each app server and adding an inbound rule with the following:

- **Pattern**: (^[^\?]*\~.*\?.*$)|(^[^\?]*\~.*$)
- **Action**: Abort Request

Hopefully that's of some use. A scan after putting this in place gave a result of "Not vulnerable" for this exploit.

Answer (score 3):

For myself I used a request filtering deny sequence entry in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <denyUrlSequences>               
            <add sequence="~" />
          </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This passes the [scanner](https://github.com/irsdl/IIS-ShortName-Scanner) tests I have run against it.

Comment: Hi Strake, this was already in place in my environment but forgot to mention that. My above solution was needed in addition to this but may only be relevant when behind a load balancer maybe!

Comment: Interesting. For me I have on-premise installs in multiple locations so I was looking for the most extensible solution without adding a dependency. So far the deny sequence has been working in my cases.